# TOML multi-level table syntax inside array -- illegal or not

Tags: toml

I'm seeing an error during parsing with the Python and JS parsers. I can't seem to find an example in the TOML repo about whether this should be accepted or not:

```
[[somearray]]
one.two = false # fails, '.' not allowed in key
```

I know I can express this as:

```
[[somearray]]
   [somearray.one]
   two = false # OK
```

The TOML readme offers this example (among others):

```
[fruit]
apple.color = "red"
apple.taste.sweet = true
```

which does not involve arrays but seems to legitimize this syntax.

I also observe that a plain file with this content:

```
apple.color = "red"
```

is rejected. In conclusion, until you enter "table mode" (so to say) with an actual bracketed table, keys can only be singles.

Now again, in the [TOML readme](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#table) it says (although in the tables section):

*"Dotted keys define everything to the left of each dot as a table."*

Obviously, if mainstream parsers choke on it, it's not a good idea to use it, but I'd like to understand if/why it's a known no-no. Is here some ambiguity I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These cases are confirmed valid TOML, per the 1.0 spec, which adds many more examples: https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/blob/1.0.0/toml.md

Answer (score 0):

The following is definitely valid Toml syntax:

```
[[somearray]]
one.two = false
```

It should result in a model that is equivalent to this Json syntax:

```
{
    "somearray": [
        {
            "one": {
                "two": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It can be validated [here](https://toml-parser.com/).

Dotted keys should indeed define everything to the left of each dot as a table.